# jQueryValidate: Cannot Validate Fields

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm struggling to validate the a form, but only the email address is being validated. Here's my snippet:

```
    $('#toggle-delivery').click( function() {       
      $("#validate-info").validate({         
        rules: {
    email_address: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          }
phone_number: {
required: true,
digits: true,
minlength: 9
}
    shipping_first_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
          }
    shipping_last_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
          }
    shipping_address_1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
          }
        }
      }).form(); 
    });
```

This ensures the form is validated only when the button `#toggle-delivery` is clicked. It's working well so far, but the phone number, shipping first name, shipping address, and shipping last name are not validated. For example, for the phone number, although I specified that only digits should be entered with a minimum of 9 characters, it automatically adds the `valid` class to the input element if you type anything into it, i.e. letters. For the other three fields that aren't validated, you can insert 1 character even though the rules say it should be a minimum of 10. It's as if the rules would be ignored.

I also tried adding custom error messages to each field:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#validate-info').validate({
onfocusout: function(e) {
            this.element(e);
        },
  messages: {
    email_address: {
      required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
      email: "Oops! This isn't a correct email format. Please check and try again."
    }
}
    });

});
```

This works well, but if I add a custom message for the phone number, it stops working. Why aren't the fields being validated?

Comment: I might be wrong, but shouldn't there be a comma between each rule in your first snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try to add commas in between your rules like this:

```
    $('#toggle-delivery').click( function() {       
  $("#validate-info").validate({         
    rules: {
email_address: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
phone_number: {
required: true,
digits: true,
minlength: 9
},
shipping_first_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
shipping_last_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
shipping_address_1: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10
      }
    }
  }).form(); 
});
```

Comment: I tried adding commas but it didn't work. The fields are not validated.